# how to catch a table structure from html code

Tags: php

I have this portion of an html page:

```
<div class="table_container p402_hide " id="div_Summer">
<table class=" stats_table" id="Summer">
<colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="">
  <th data-stat="year" align="right"  class=" sort_default_asc" >Year</th>
  <th data-stat="city" align="left"  class=" sort_default_asc" >City</th>
  <th data-stat="country" align="left"  class=" sort_default_asc" >Country</th>
  <th data-stat="countries" align="right"  class="" >Countries</th>
  <th data-stat="participants" align="right"  class="" >Participants</th>
  <th data-stat="participants_men" align="right"  class="" >Men</th>
  <th data-stat="participants_women" align="right"  class="" >Women</th>
  <th data-stat="sports" align="right"  class="" >Sports</th>
  <th data-stat="events" align="right"  class="" >Events</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr  class="">
   <td align="right" ><a href="/olympics/summer/2012/">2012</a></td>
   <td align="left"  csk="London:2012">London</td>
   <td align="left"  csk="Great Britain:2012">Great Britain</td>
   <td align="right" >205</td>
   <td align="right" >10,519</td>
   <td align="right" >5,864</td>
   <td align="right" >4,655</td>
   <td align="right" >32</td>
   <td align="right" >302</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to grab the structure of the table (what I written is only a portion of it). I'm trying to do this with this PHP code:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/');
#echo $html;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);


$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
echo $node;

?>
```

When I run the script I get the error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

How could I do?

Comment: Using `var_dump` instead of `echo` you can see what is and what contains any variable *(whatever the type)*. What do you mean by "catch a table structure"? What is your desired output?

Comment: My goal is to catch the value "2012" and put it in a new links and then do other things. Since there are other value (2008, 2004 etc. etc.) I want to make a cycle e catch at every cycle this value (year). I used to work with php some years ago and I remember how to catch all html tags, but now I forget all.

Comment: I suggest to use an XPath query to easily target what you are looking for. Something like: `//table[@id="Summer"]/tbody/tr/td/a`

Comment: I never used that, I don't even know where to begin